# Oncreate method of MainActivity is never called in Android app

Tags: android, oncreate

I have a very strange problem. My Android is working fine on all Android versions, but not on Android KitKat. When debugging app, oncreate method of mainActivity is never called. The app starts, but with a blank screen that keeps alive without exception... Oncreate method is never called. No error messages, no exception, nothing... Any ideas?

Comment: Which `onCreate()` did you override?

Comment: @TheWanderer the onCreate() method of my launcher activity. In Android 4.4, this onCreate method is never called and screen remains black...

Comment: What do you mean my android is working fine on all android versions?Are you using a real device or emulator

Comment: There are two `onCreate()` methods inside the Activity class. Which one did you override?

Comment: Real device. I've Android 6.0, 7, 8 and 9 devices. All works fine. But on a Android KitKat device, onCreate method is never called for some strange reason. Users with KitKat devices are also announcing this.

Comment: @TheWanderer I extend AppCompatActivity, and it seems it only have on onCreate method?

Comment: Can you please just put your code in the question?

Comment: Just to make it clear, is it `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)` OR `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` ? Because with the 2-arg method you could get that kind of behavior...

Comment: It should have only one argument that other one is for special cases and also needs the first one always as well.